# How to open Sprint Burndown report in Visual Studio 12

Tags: visual-studio-2012, burndowncharts

When I use VS10 Sprint Burndown Report opens in VS.
Now I use VS12 and report opens in my default browser.
How could I open it in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, opening an SSRS report from within VS2010 did open the report within the browser of VS; however, this behavior has changed in VS2012 to open the report in your default browser. This is due to the fact that VS2012 no longer has a web browser (as was the case with VS2010).

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way in which this is possible. In 2012, Web Access is the central location for that kind of report.